# Making a diamond div with an arrow inside it that can expand

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been searching the web for quite a while now and couldnt find any solutions so that why i'm asking here.

In the following images is my problem displayed.

http://www.digitusweb.nl/nieuw/wp-content/themes/waarbeek/images/what%20the%20code.jpg

how can i make this diamond shaped div. I've tried   `transform: rotate(-45deg);` on a div that is 220px X 220px, and than let the content of that div have   `transform: rotate(45deg);`

And another question.. How can i let the little border-arrow transist into the bigger blue rectangualr diamond shaped div?

Comment: you can use borders !! http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/ It works for triangle, It must work for diamonds.

Comment: Yes i've made the little triangle with this css border trick. But the bigger diamond cant be done with this cause only the outline is 'bordered'

Comment: mhm.... What if you put two opposite triangles side by side ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9XDtn/2/ Horrible px based stuff, but a starting point.

Comment: Ok i've got the top part of the image done. 

Now my only problem is how to let the top part transist into the bottom part of the image. Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 2):

The transform CSS attribute is part of CSS3 spec and still unsupported in some browsers. You will want a more cross-platform CSS class to cover browser specific attributes like the following (which was taken directly from [css3please.com](http://css3please.com))

```
.box_rotate {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);  /* Chrome, Safari 3.1+ */
     -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);  /* Firefox 3.5-15 */
      -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);  /* IE 9 */
       -o-transform: rotate(45deg);  /* Opera 10.50-12.00 */
          transform: rotate(45deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.10+ */
}
```

Comment: k great, didn't have that yet. 

I've edited my question. Is there also a fix for this?

Comment: This will not fix the content inside sadly but it is a must to point out.

Comment: Check out the answer from @JoshPowell for more on how to handle the content. He creates the arrow with a 30px border-right in a :before and some more tricks.

Answer (score 1):

Alright I went a head with the `rotate` style but I had to make the content `absolute` to enable it's own transform style.

```
.di {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid lightBlue;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 50px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    position: relative;
}

.di:before {
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 2px;
    bottom: 2px;
    border-right: 30px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-top: 30px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 0 solid transparent;
}

div.di span {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 100px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_JM/LJuCZ/).

Phew that Second one was a good challenge,

View the fiddle to see the css and here is the jQuery I used,

```
$('.bigDi').on('click', function() {
    $('.bigDi, .content').toggleClass('active');               
});
```

Second question [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_JM/XmS94/1/)

Comment: Great! this will help me some more.

I guess, to make this diamond so big as in the bottom part of my image, i will need some jquery etc right?

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not following you. What are you trying to do?

Comment: You´ve helped me on the top part of this image: http://www.digitusweb.nl/nieuw/wp-content/themes/waarbeek/images/what%20the%20code.jpg 

But i´m still stuck at the bottom part. When clicking the diamond, it should expand and show the content inside (as displayed in the image). I guess this can be done with js or jquery only?

Comment: Yes you can with java, let me see if I can make something real fast. You can do it to a hover state with css as well.

Comment: Refer to my questions edit at the bottom.